# Programmatically detect if SharePoint 2013 is connected to OWA Server

Tags: 2013, development, office-web-apps

SharePoint 2013 can be configured to use an Office Web Apps (OWA) server in order to display/preview Microsoft Office documents directly within the browser. This can be seen for example when opening the callout of a document or when clicking the "new document" button.

The question is, how can I programmatically detect if SharePoint is connected to an OWA server? I didn’t find anything public on the SharePoint API.

What I am looking for is something like below methods:

- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPWOPIHost.IsWOPIEnabled(SPWeb web)`
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileUrlRedirectManager.HasWopiBinding()`

However everything I found is internal and I do not want to use any reflection stuff. Does anybody have a clue, if SharePoint provides a public method indicating whether it is connected to an OWA Server?

JFYI – in case you have access to an OWA server, you can link SharePoint to it with following Cmdlet:

`New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "officewebapps.company.com"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Get-SPWOPIBinding cmdlet that can provide the information resulting from the New-SPWOPIBinding command.

In your example, it would be Get-SPWOPIBinding -Server "officewebapps.company.com"

There is another cmdlet Get-SPWOPIZone that'll give you the list of bindings within the zone. More about it and the [Get-SPWOPIBinding command is here in TechNet.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219450(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: The thing is that I want to get this information programmatically (from C# code running within SharePoint) and not via PowerShell. The class behind the Cmdlet you are referring to is `SPCmdletGetWOPIBinding` (which is internal too). And internally it uses `SPFileUrlRedirectManager.HasWopiBinding()`. And I would like to be able to do so too.. ;)

Comment: are you trying to access the OWA from an external C# app using the WOPI protocol?

Comment: No, I am developing a solution within SharePoint and I want to know, if the server is connected to OWA in order to be able to redirect to a correct URL (either open a document via WOPIFrame.aspx [browser] or in the client application [local]). This is just an example, another one would be the simulation of the "new document" button in lists, which needs to be different when OWA is available/link and when it isn't.